# Fast Fourier Transform in C

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I have a time domain data of an electric field(windowed) at a point, say $(x,y)$.
The time is around 33 picoseconds and sampled at 20,000 points.

To convert this data to frequency domain I am using FFT. The steps I follow are:

1) I take the Fourier transform of the electric field in a frequency range (say $f_1$ to $f_2$ in 20,000 points) and over the time interval of 33 picoseonds and get complex amplitude from this step.

2) Now I take the norm of the complex amplitude to get the magnitude of complex amplitude.

3) I find the phase$(-\pi, \pi)$ using real and imaginary parts of the complex amplitude in the defined frequency range.

4) Now I multiply the cosine of the phase with the magnitude of the complex amplitude to get the real part of the complex amplitude.

5) Then I plot the absolute value of the real amplitude versus frequency.

However, after doing all of this, I don't obtain the right frequency spectrum. I don't know whether my procedure is correct or not. I guess, the problem might be with sampling.

Can someone comment on it.

Comment: In step 2, you "take norm of the complex amplitude to get the **real amplitude**" and in step 4, you "multiply phase with norm of complex amplitude to get the **real amplitude**" -- only one of these is correct. Also, multiplying with the phase (a number between $0$ and $2\pi$ - or maybe between $-\pi$ and $\pi$) does not look like a sensible step anyway

Comment: Actually in step 2 I meant, take norm to get magnitude of complex amplitude. Then I multiply this magnitude with cosine of phase to get real part of the amplitude. I will correct it.